# Trying to retrieve values in webservice constructor method

Tags: c#, jquery, xml, web-services

I'm trying to pass multiple values through ajax which are stored in jquery variable and and want to retrieve that values in webservice constructor method.
code for jquery Ajax

```
 $("#formsubmit").click(function(){
            var obj = { name: $("#contact_name").val(), email: $("#contact_email").val(),phone:$("#contact_phone").val(),
            month:$("#rfp_requestmonth").val(),phone:$("#contact_phone").val(),month:$("#rfp_requestmonth").val,
            date:$("#rfp_requestdate").val(),year:$("#rfp_requestyear").val(),time:$("#requested_time").val,
            guest:$("#number_guests").val(),comments:$("#contact_comments").val()};  

         $.ajax({
             type:$('.rfpform').attr('method'),
             url: "Thankyou.asmx/ThanksMail",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: JSON.stringify(obj),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (response) {
                 var names = response.d;
                 alert(names);
     location.assign(/^http/i.test(nextWebPageId) ? nextWebPageId : (location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + "/?pg=" + nextWebPageId));
             },
             failure: function (response) {
                 alert(response.d);
             }
         });
```

webservice method where i want to retrieve values.

```
 public  Thankyou()
    {
 MailMessage o = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient("ervices.com", 38);
        smtpobj.EnableSsl = false;
 o.From = new MailAddress("esh_p07@hotmail.com");
        o.To.Add("esh07@gmail.com");
        o.Subject = "The Culver Hotel Event Inquiry Form";
        o.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string htmlBody;
        htmlBody = "You have received an email via the<b>[ver Hotel<b>Event Inquiry form.<br/><b>From:[#text:contact_name#]</b><br/><b>Phone:</b><br/><b>Requested Date:</b><br/>;<b>Requested Time:</b><br/><b>Number of Guests:</b><br/><b>Comments:</b>";
        o.Body = htmlBody;
        smtpobj.Send(o);
}
```

I want valuesstored in variable 'obj' to be filled in respective fields in "htmlBody" part in webmethod constructor.any idea would be appreciated.